# Stuck with MacbookPro when booting a bootable USB containing MACOS Installation image

Tags: mac, usb, macbook-pro, bootable-media, reinstall

I've got a MacBook Pro (2012 or 2013 model) with no Mac partition, I've tried to install Mac using recovery mode but It always downloads **'MacOS Lion Mountain'** which is outdated so my mac keeps crashing each 10 minutes.
I've tried to create a bootable usb using Windows in order to install *Mojave* or *Sierra*, I used *TransMAC* and *AnyBoot* to write the **.dmg** image on the usb. The problem is that my MAC doesn't detect the usb as bootable device (formatted and converted as a GPT Partition), it's either disabled or doesn't show up at all. Despite, it works fine with FAT32 and NTFS Partitions when I was trying to install Ubuntu. 
**What can I do in order to install an non-outdated MACOS (such as Sierra) on my MacBook?** 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, until you get Mac OS working, you might consider installing Linux, e.g., Ubuntu: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/How%20to%20install%20Ubuntu%20on%20MacBook%20using%20USB%20Stick *N.B.* That cannot be done on newer Macs, yet:  https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251087440

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309399/how-can-i-download-an-older-version-of-os-x-macos/309400#309400

Comment: Find out exactly which model you have. Look on the bottom for the model number A1xxx and then search for that.

Comment: Don't search by model number - the same model number could cover 5 years of different Macs [irritating, but true]. Use Everymac's [Ultimate Mac Lookup](https://everymac.com/ultimate-mac-lookup/)